# Error in update a cart in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3

Fatal error: **Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first** statement or after any declare call in the script in `.../vendor/zendframework/zend-filter/src/AbstractFilter.php on line 10`

what is the solution in this case?

Comment: Did you create any custom module ? after which the error shows?

Comment: The error simply means you have not declared a namespace to a class. Try to check files you have created or modified.

Comment: no files changed, I'll update to 2.3.3 because I also had a break with version 2.3.1
I hope then the error will disappear